# Creating simple hangman program in java, trouble with for loop

Tags: java, string, loops

```
public class Game {

public static void main(String[] args) {
String secretWord = "frog";

System.out.println("Word has " + secretWord.length() + " letters.");
System.out.println("Guess a letter: ");

int correctGuesses = 0;

int strikes = 5;

Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

while (strikes > 0) {
```

here the loop cycles through the characters in a String, and checks if the user input guessedLetter matches a char in the string. right now the loop cycles through each char starting with the first char in the string through the last, the user must guess the letters in the exact order of they are arranged in the string, how can I fix this so that any character input matching a character in the String will be correct rather than the characters having to be in order?

```
    for (int i = 0; i < secretWord.length(); i++) {


        char guessedLetter = input.next().charAt(0);

        char currentLetter = secretWord.charAt(i);

        if (guessedLetter == currentLetter) {

            correctGuesses++;
            System.out.printf("Correct Guess! %d Letters Left!\n", secretWord.length() - correctGuesses);
        }

        else if (guessedLetter != currentLetter) {

            strikes--;
            System.out.printf("Incorrect: You Have %d Chances Left..\n", strikes);
        }

        if (strikes == 0) {

            System.out.println("You Are Out of Chances! Game over!");
        }

        else if (correctGuesses == secretWord.length()) {

            System.out.println("You Got It! The Word is: " + secretWord);
        }
    }

}
```

}

Comment: would it not be easier - and cleaner - to use `String.indexOf (char)` see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(int)

Comment: could you give an example of how I could use this to clean up the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try it as follows:

1. move all the characters of secretWord to a map (key would be the character and the value would be incidences of that character in the string).
2. read the character from the keyboard and interate (basically, your logic).

Here is the code.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String secretWord = "frog";

    Map<Character, Integer> mapOfLetters = new HashMap<>();

    for (char c : secretWord.toCharArray()) {
        int count = 1;
        if (mapOfLetters.containsKey(c)) {
            count = mapOfLetters.get(c) + 1;
        }
        mapOfLetters.put(c, count);
    }

    System.out.println("Word has " + secretWord.length() + " letters.");
    System.out.println("Guess a letter: ");

    int correctGuesses = 0;

    int strikes = 5;

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    while (strikes > 0 && !mapOfLetters.isEmpty()) {

        char guessedLetter = input.next().charAt(0);

        if (mapOfLetters.containsKey(guessedLetter)) {

            correctGuesses++;
            System.out.printf("Correct Guess! %d Letters Left!\n", secretWord.length() - correctGuesses);

            int count = mapOfLetters.get(guessedLetter) - 1;
            if (count == 0) {
                mapOfLetters.remove(guessedLetter);
            } else {
                mapOfLetters.put(guessedLetter, count);
            }
        } else {
            strikes--;
            System.out.printf("Incorrect: You Have %d Chances Left..\n", strikes);
        }
    }

    if (strikes == 0) {
        System.out.println("You Are Out of Chances! Game over!");
    } else if(mapOfLetters.isEmpty()){
        System.out.println("You Got It! The Word is: " + secretWord);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
guessedLetter = input.next().charAt(0);
```

If you want to match the whole `UserInput` there should not be `charAt(0)`.
On the other hand, if you just want to match any character, at first time you can test `guessedLetter == currentLetter` is true, then just exit program.

By the way, if you like, just google "KMP algorithm" to learn how to match String.

Comment: hm I don't really know what you mean about testing if guessedLetter == currentLetter is true, could you explain?

Comment: sorry i'm good at english.but i will try to explain:it means when the programe excute to here and calculate  the result of guessedLetter == currentLetter is true .